# How To Select 10 Top records in SQL

Tags: sql

i have a table in my database i want to select 10 top post than have must view count
what is good query for that?

Comment: The answer depends on which db server you're using. Comprehensive discussion here: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/top-n-queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used this query

```
select TOP(10) * from tblNews order by viewcount desc
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select top 10 * from tablename
```